# Why is .net 4.5 not showing in registry

Tags: .net, registry, .net-4.5

Why is the .net Version (if installed) not showing in the registry like the other versions?

Registry `HKLM / Software / Microsoft` with .net 4.5 installed, but no Version 4.5

[image: .net 4.5 not in registry]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[.NET 4.5 is an in place replacement to 4.0](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx).

That's what you are seeing.

It means that for most intents and purposes, 4.5 *is* 4.0.

Comment: Good article, but still confusing why 3/3.5 is side-by-side and 4/4.5 is in place. But thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score -1):

You will find some notes about this on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568.aspx